# Defining a log spiral from three points

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, nonlinear-system, interpolation

Let us have three points: $p_0 = (0,0)$, $p_1 = (a,0)$ and $p_2=(b,c)$. (We can assume that $b<a$.)

I want to define a log spiral (in polar space) of the form $r=r_0e^{k\theta}$ from some $center=(x,y)$ that passes through the three points. We can assume the spiral passes through $p_0$ when $\theta = 0$, so that $r_0^2=x^2+y^2$.

We must compute values for $r_0$, $k$ and another parameter that would allows us to find $centre$.

It is easy to setup a system of equations to represent the problem, but it is very ugly, and I am not sure how to solve it computationally.

For example, if $\theta_0 = cos^{-1}[(r_0^2 + r_1^2 - a^2)/2r_0r_1]$ and $\theta_1 = cos^{-1}[(r_0^2 + r_2^2 - d^2)/2r_0r_2]$, where $d^2=b^2+c^2$, we can have equations, such as:

$r_1 = r_0e^{k\theta_0} = r_0e^{k\times cos^{-1}[(r_0^2 + r_1^2 - a^2)/2r_0r_1]}$

$r_2 = r_0e^{k\theta_1} = r_0e^{k\times cos^{-1}[(r_0^2 + r_2^2 - d^2)/2r_0r_2]}$

and another uglier equation involving the angle $\theta_2$ between $p_1$ and $p_2$: $r_2 = r_1e^{k\theta_2}$.

There must be a better way of setting the equations to solve the problem, involving a better representation of the problem, for example a complex representation, or some clever geometry.

EDIT: **Complex Representation**

We can represents the points in the complex plan as:  $p_0 = 0$, $p_1 = a$ and $p_2=b + ci$.

Then, the problem is equivalent to finding two complex numbers **z** and **s** such that the graph of the complex-valued function over the reals $z^\theta + s$ passes through the points. **z** should not be a muliple of $e^i$, in which case it will reduce to a circle. In this case, **s** is the centre of the spiral.

Comment: If you have $\theta=0$ for $p_0$, then $y=0$.

Comment: No! It only means that $p_0$ is at a distance $r_0$ from c. The assumption is simply that $p_0$ is the beginning of the spiral, which we can always assume in general, as log spirals are self-similar.

Comment: So that means that the $\theta$ is an angle that is not measured from the horizontal. Also, why do you use $c$ for $p_2$ and for the center? I assume that you want to calculate the center

Comment: Fixed the notation problem. The polar representation of the spiral is in a different vector space. Part of the problem is to find out how to map the centre of that space to the Cartesian space of the points. All angles are relative to the line from the centre to $p_0$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one method. Consider the three given points in the complex plane
and the unknown $\,z\,$

$$ p_0 = 0,\quad p_1=a,\quad p_2 = b+i\,c,\quad z = x+i\,y \tag{1}$$

where $\,z\,$ is the center of the logarithmic spiral. The given conditions
are not enough to uniquely specify the spiral. However, if we
assume that $\,p_0,p_1,p_2\,$ have equal angular difference from $\,z,\,$
then the equation

$$ w := (p_1-z)/(p_0-z) = (p_2-z)/(p_1-z) \tag{2}$$

has the solution

$$ z = a^2/(2a-b-i\,c). \tag{3}$$

The equation of the spiral is

$$ a(n) := z + (p_0-z)w^n. \tag{4}$$

Here is a simple example. Let$\,a=1,\, b=2,\, c=1.\,$ Then the calculations produce

$$z=i,\quad p_0-z=-i,\quad w=1+i,\quad a(n) = i - i(1+i)^n. \tag{5} $$

The points $\,(0, 1, 2+i, 2+3i,5i,-4+5i)\,$
for $\,0\le n\le 5\,$ are on a logarithmic spiral.

Comment: Is it clear that the point $z$ in fact is centre of a spiral passing through that three points? And even it is, this does not help with the general problem.

Comment: @Vakarelov Thanks for that comment. I will give more details soon.

Comment: How to find $z$ for $4$ and more points in this approach?

Comment: @dtn For that, please ask a new question.