# How does one invert $e^{(k+i)\theta}+e^{(k-i)\theta}=e^{k\theta}+c$ to obtain $\theta$, given known $k,c$?

Tags: complex-numbers, inverse-problems

I need to find a real solution for $\theta$ in the following complex equation:

$e^{(k+i)\theta} + e^{(k-i)\theta} = e^{k\theta} + c$

Here $k$ and $c$ are positive real numbers.

The problem is related to the problem of finding a log spiral given by $r = r_0 e^{(k+i)\theta} + z$ with known $r_0$ and $k$, which passes through two points $z_0$ and $z_1$. In the equation, c = $\dfrac{d^2}{r_0^2}$ where $d$ is the distance between $z_0$ and $z_1$.

An approximate solution (with given error bound) can also be useful.

A more general question about such spirals is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4291260/defining-a-log-spiral-from-three-points)

Comment: Using $(e^{i\theta}+e^{-i\theta})/2=\cos(\theta)$ and rearranging, the equation can be equivalently expressed as $e^{k\theta}\left[2\cos(\theta)-1\right]=c$. I don't think $e^{k\theta}\left[2\cos(\theta)-1\right]$ has an elementary inverse.

Comment: Actually, I got the equation from the trigonometric form. I was hoping that moving to the complex plain will simply the problem. The next question, than, is: Can there an elementary numerical approximation, using Taylor polynomials, for example? I am hoping to an $O(1)$ method.